# HTML element won't go under two divs floating next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with 3 elements, the first and second one float next to each other, but the third one has no float and has a width of 80%. For some reason it goes up with them, even though i'm adding `float:none;`

Here's my code:

```
<div class="elem1">

</div>
<div class="elem2">

</div>
<div class="elem3">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.elem1{
  width:40%;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background:#f00;
}
.elem2{
  width:40%;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
  background:#ff0;
}

.elem3{
  width:80%;
  height:200px;
  background:#f0f;
  margin:auto;
  float:none;
}
```

Here's a link: https://jsfiddle.net/woa0hvj9/

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the float.  [New fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/woa0hvj9/2/).

```
.elem3{
  clear: both;
  width:80%;
  height:200px;
  background:#f0f;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `clear: both;` to the `.elem3` div. The third div is filling the space of the floated elements, so to avoid this use the clear property.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to clear floats.**

A more commonly used (and better) technique by web professionals in such scenarios is called `clearfix`

Wrap the .elem1 and .elem2 in another div and give it a class say , `.clearfix`.

Use the `after` pseudo-element to the clearfix class. Add the following class to your css code:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **Self-clear** the floating elements using:

> overflow: hidden;